# '@' sign on mac commandline

Tags: macos, terminal

What does a '@' sign mean in mac command line next to file permissions?

```
-rw-r--r--@ 1 user staff 1111 May 3 15:10 MyFile.txt
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The @ indicates that the file has associated [extended attributes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_file_attributes).

You can find explanation in the [man page](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ls.1.html):

> **The Long Format**
>
> If the -l option is given, the
>   following information is displayed for
>   each file: file mode, number of links,
>   owner name, group name, number of
>   bytes in the file, abbreviated month,
>   day-of-month file was last modified,
>   hour file last modified, minute file
>   last modified, and the pathname.  In
>   addition, for each directory whose
>   contents are displayed, the total
>   number of 512-byte blocks used by the
>   files in the directory is displayed on
>   a line by itself, immediately before
>   the information for the files in the
>   directory.  **If the file or directory
>   has extended attributes, the
>   permissions field printed by the -l
>   option is followed by a '@'
>   character.**  Otherwise, if the file
>   or directory has extended security
>   information (such as an access control
>   list), the permissions field printed
>   by the -l option is followed by a '+'
>   character.

Comment: Also, you can see more information about these extended attributes if you add `-@` to the `ls` options.  And if you see the `+` character that means you have ACLs (access control lists), you can see more about those by adding `-e`.

Now that those xattrs and ACL are becoming more common, I like to see those things by default, so I very often do `ls -l@e` instead of just `ls -l` nowadays.